# How do I fix Vue JS alert

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple `index.html` file that I am using to learn Vue. I have attached a click event on a button and it is supposed to alert the user.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hello Visitor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
            <input type="text"> </br> </br>
            <button v-on:click="greet" class="btn btn-primary">Greet Me!</button>   
    </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
       message: 'What is your name?'
    },
    methods: {
       greet: function(){
          alert("Hello to you too.");
       },
    }
});
```

I thought that the function needed the `event` param in the function but that did not help. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Your Vue app is bound to `#app`. Stuff that happens outside that div, Vue doesn't parse or know about.

Comment: Your button is not inside of your `el`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Vue app is bound to `#app`.

Stuff that happens outside that div, Vue doesn't parse or know about.

Move your button inside the `#app` div and it should function. You may also want to give your `<button>` a `type="button"` - that'll prevent it from trying to submit a form, which is the default behavior. (You can also do `<button @click.prevent="greet">` to accomplish the same thing. The `.prevent` prevents the default behavior.)

Comment: Whoa. I was completely blind there. I'll definitely add the `type=button`. Thanks a million!